# get table rate shipping data in Woocommerce REST API

Tags: api, rest

I am trying to get all active shipping methods in Woocommerce REST API. How can I achieve this. I am new to woocommerce REST API, Any help is much appreciated.

I want response something  like this -

```json
{
  "shipping_methods": {
    "method_id": "method_title"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I , finally, come up with the solution. It may help others. 
Below is complete code to get all table rate shipping data including shipping zones, shipping methods by zone and rates by zone -

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $json_file=file_get_contents('php://input');
 $jsonvalue= json_decode($json_file,true);

 global $wpdb;
 global $woocommerce;

 $active_methods   = array();

$shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
//echo "<pre>";print_r($shipping_methods);

foreach ( $shipping_methods as $id => $shipping_method ) {

 if ( isset( $shipping_method->enabled ) && 'yes' === $shipping_method->enabled ) {

        $data_arr = array( 'title' => $shipping_method->title, 'tax_status' => $shipping_method->tax_status );  

    if($id=='table_rate'){          

     $raw_zones = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT zone_id, zone_name, zone_order FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones order by zone_order ASC;");

   //echo "<pre>";print_r($raw_zones);

    $shipping = array();
    $shippingarr = array();
    foreach ($raw_zones as $raw_zone) {

         $zones = new WC_Shipping_Zone($raw_zone->zone_id);

         $zone_id = $zones->zone_id; 
         $zone_name = $zones->zone_name; 
         $zone_enabled = $zones->zone_enabled; 
         $zone_type = $zones->zone_type; 
         $zone_order = $zones->zone_order; 

         $shipping['zone_id'] = $zone_id;
         $shipping['zone_name'] = $zone_name;
         $shipping['zone_enabled'] = $zone_enabled;
         $shipping['zone_type'] = $zone_type;
         $shipping['zone_order'] = $zone_order;

         $shipping_methods = $zones->shipping_methods; 
         foreach($shipping_methods as $shipping_method){

    $methodid = $shipping_method["number"];
             $raw_rates[$methodid]['rates'] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_table_rates WHERE shipping_method_id={$methodid};",ARRAY_A);


         }

     $shipping['shipping_methods'] = $raw_rates;

    $raw_country = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT location_code FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations WHERE zone_id={$zone_id};",ARRAY_N);

         $shipping['countries'] = $raw_country;

         $shippingarr[] = $shipping;


    }

        $data_arr['shipping_zones'] = $shippingarr; 

        }

        $active_methods[ $id ] = $data_arr;

    }

  } 


     if(!empty($shippingarr)){

     $result['success']='true';
     $result['error']="0";
     $result['msg']='Shipping methos found.';  
     $result['data']=$active_methods; 

     }else{

    $result['success']='true';
    $result['error']="0";
    $result['msg']='Shipping methos found.';  
    $result['data']= array();    

    } 

    echo json_encode($result); `
```